# Replacing an element in Kotlin 2D list

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to replace an element in 2D list
hand instead of one element at one specified index all element are changing

this is the list

```
`private val printS: MutableList<MutableList<Char>> = mutableListOf(mutableListOf())`
```

This is how I literate them

```
 // adding S to the list
  for (i in 1..seat) printS[0].add('S') 
  // now we have list of S char in the printS list
  for (i in 1..row) {   
    printS.add(printS[0])
}
```

now try to change list 5 element 5
`printS[5][5] = 'B'`

this is the result

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 S S S S S B S
2 S S S S S B S
3 S S S S S B S
4 S S S S S B S
5 S S S S S B S
6 S S S S S B S
7 S S S S S B S
```

all the lists have changed not just one
I need to just change one Char so the result should be

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 S S S S S S S
2 S S S S S S S
3 S S S S S S S
4 S S S S S S S
5 S S S S S S S
6 S S S S S B S
7 S S S S S S S
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work... try providing a working example on https://play.kotlinlang.org/ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit (based on OP's clarification in the first comment below):

```
val rows = 7
val cols = 7

val result = MutableList(rows) { MutableList(cols) { 'S' } }

result[5][5] = 'B'
```

Still valid:

Your code does not work because the inner loop is not nested due to you not having put parentheses on the outer loop:

```
for (i in 1..seat) printS[0].add('S') 
  for (i in 1..row) {   
    printS.add(printS[0])
}
```

This means – properly formatted - nothing else than:

```
for (i in 1..seat) {
  printS[0].add('S')
}
for (i in 1..row) {   
  printS.add(printS[0])
}
```

Obsolete:

This should work:

```
val rows = 7
val cols = 7

val result: MutableList<MutableList<Char>> = mutableListOf()

for (row in 0 until rows) {
  result.add(mutableListOf())
  for (col in 0 until rows) {
    result[row].add(if (row = 5 && col == 5) 'B' else 'S')
  }
}

result.forEach(::println)
```

Output:

```
[S, S, S, S, S, S, S]
[S, S, S, S, S, S, S]
[S, S, S, S, S, S, S]
[S, S, S, S, S, S, S]
[S, S, S, S, S, S, S]
[S, S, S, S, S, B, S]
[S, S, S, S, S, S, S]
```

But a shorter way to create this matrix would be:

```
val result = List(rows) { row -> 
  List(cols) { col -> 
    if (row == 5 && col == 5) 'B' else 'S' 
  } 
}
```

Comment: hay thx for your help I made my question a bit bad so the the output I'm looking for is just to change one single char in the 2d list I have the program is looped so you can chose many seats and any time you chose one an 'S' will be replaced with an 'B' and will be printed the first time list get printer all is 'S' so I should adjust the list after the first print when the first seat is chosen it will print with b and list should change for the next print

Comment: @BigBeastDGX Added an edit at the beginning of my answer to reflect your clarification.